# SQLITE3 First Start and Understanding

Tags: database, xcode, sqlite

Ok guys ive searched alot in the web but its hard to understand for me.
i search for sqlite because i work with xcode and there i want to make a login witha sqlite database..

so i know sqlite is a database.

but is it a program i download to configure?
is it a website i have to configure?
do i have to have a website for it?
how do i connect a register(if user sign up) to my databse?
what programming language is needed?

could u guys explain me this questions? and give me some helpful links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually SQLite is a in-process library that implements

- A self-contained(No dependency with Database Management System Software, just required binaries that you can download from http://www.sqlite.org/)
- Serverless(you can place your SQLite data file on your local file system)
- Zero-configuration(almost zero configuration to install and run it)
- Transactional SQL database engine(capabilities of relational model of database)

Means you can store data in a single independent file with the capabilities of relational model of database. You can use it to store data for your web application, desktop application or on any other supported platform. You should have the knowledge of SQL for using it.

Here are some helpful links:

http://www.SQLite.org/

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/302814/Can-we-use-Sqlite-database-in-asp-net

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SQLiteCSharp.aspx

A very useful SQLite manager: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/